# × InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('') is not a valid name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an error in react application but after few hours I am not able to find the bug. Application works only some pages throws me this error: ×
InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('') is not a valid name.
Here is the code of PageDetail.tsx line 685 of render method mentioned in the error log:

```
  public render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <FormWithReduxPage
        setItem={this.props.pageDetailSetItem}
        pageTitle={i18n.t("pages.page.detail.pageTitle")}
        pageSubtitle={i18n.t("pages.page.detail.pageSubtitle")}
        spreadScreenState="page"
        apiUrlPrefix={"page" + "/" + this.props.match.params.lang}
        validator={PageValidator}
        onItemLoaded={this.checkFileTemplateIndex}
        emptyItem={emptyPage}
        id={this.props.match.params.id}
      >
        {(p) => (
          <Page
            {...p}
            removeDynamicDataField={this.removeDynamicDataField}
            show={this.state.showAddRow}
            closeAdd={this.closeAddRow}
            showEditRow={this.openAddRow}
            saveData={this.insertNewDynamicRow}
            dynamicEditedItem={this.state.dynamicEditedItem}
            updatedItem={this.state.updatedItem}
            setEditedItem={this.startEditItem}
            setUpdatedItem={this.updateEditedItem}
            stopEditing={this.saveEditedItem}
            changeLang={this.changeLanguage}
          />
        )}
      </FormWithReduxPage>
    );
  }
```

Here is the console log.

```
The above error occurred in one of your React components:
in Unknown (at FormWithRedux.tsx:293)
in FormWithReduxPage (at PageDetail.tsx:685)
in PageDetailComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
in Connect(PageDetailComponent) (created by Route)
in Route (at Auth.tsx:557)
in Switch (at Auth.tsx:554)
in div (at Auth.tsx:553)
in main (at Auth.tsx:383)
in div (at Auth.tsx:381)
in div (at Auth.tsx:380)
in Page (at Auth.tsx:696)
in AuthComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
in Connect(AuthComponent) (created by Route)
in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(AuthComponent)))
in withRouter(Connect(AuthComponent)) (at App.tsx:126)
in div (at App.tsx:122)
in div (at App.tsx:63)
in Router (at App.tsx:62)
in I18nextProvider (at App.tsx:61)
in AdminApp (created by Context.Consumer)
in Connect(AdminApp) (at src/index.tsx:11)
in Provider (at src/index.tsx:10)
```

Here is the screenshot [image]

Can somebody help me please to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now there is a code of render method mentioned in console log. Hope it help.